# updating xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

hey there i have an xml file that has what i need to do is to  add  an event with same location name A

```
  <timetable>
  <location name="A" >
         <event >
                  <title>EVENT TITLE </title>
                  <subtitle>Amman -text </subtitle>
                  <description>Amman -text </description>
         </event>

    </location>
    </timetable>
```

so it can be like this

```
<timetable>
  <location name="A" >
         <event >
                  <title>EVENT TITLE </title>
                  <subtitle>Amman -text </subtitle>
                  <description>Amman -text </description>
         </event>
         <event >
                  <title>EVENT TITLE </title>
                  <subtitle>Amman -text </subtitle>
                  <description>Amman -text </description>
         </event>

    </location>
    </timetable>
```

i got stuck in my php code where i want to cheack if the event is created or not if its created modify my xml with name of the event and add the new one

this is my full php inserting code `

```
           if(isset($_GET['coname'])){

          $coid = $_GET['id'];

          $cname=$_GET['coname'];

          $title = $_POST ['title'];
          $sub = $_POST ['sub'];
          $description = $_POST ['description'];
          $location = $_POST ['location'];
          $event = $_POST ['event'] ;

          $str =$_POST ['str'] ;
          $end =$_POST ['end'] ;
          $topic = $_POST ['topic'] ;


          $sql="INSERT INTO timeline (title,sub,description,location,event,str,end,topic,coid)
          VALUES
          ('$title','$sub','$location','$location','$event','$str','$end','$topic','$coid')";
          if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
          echo "1 record added";

          $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timeline where coid = $coid") or  die(mysqli_error());

          $xml = '<timetable start="'.$st.'" end="'.$en.'" interval="'.$in.'"                                title="'.$da.'">';
          while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
              $loc=$r['topic'];
              $evns=$r['str'];
              $evne= $r['end'];

               $xml .= '<location name="'.$loc.'" subtext=" ">';
            $xml .= '<event start="'.$evns.'" end="'.$evne.'">';
            $xml .= "<title>".$r['title']."</title>";
            $xml .= "<subtitle>".$r['location']."</subtitle>";  
            $xml .= "<description>".$r['description']."</description>";    
             $xml .= "</event>"; 

            $xml .= "</location>";  

                 }

                 $xml .= "</timetable>";

              $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

             $sxe->asXML('xml/'.$cname.'.xml'); `
```

Comment: Hi Amer, welcome to SO. Here, you are welcome to try to solve the problem, show what you've tried and get support from very competent people. So look into `simplexml`and give it a try!

Comment: read file -> parse -> modify -> write file. pretty much like that.

Comment: Why are you using MySQL for this? XML is perfectly functional for storing information. After all, that's what it does.

Comment: You said you want to check if the event was created... in mysql or in XML?

Comment: yes it saves perfectly but when i want to add a new events under an exciting location , so i can modify the 2nd chiled 'events ; after that

Comment: @michi in the xml , after i created this with my php code i want to add a new event with the location A or B and save the xml again , but when i do that it keeps repaeting the location but with a new event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amer, rather than creating the XML from strings, I'd use the `simplexml` methods:

Inserting a new `<event>` in existing XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$loc = $xml->xpath("location[@name = 'A']")[0]; // select <location> with name = A 
$event = $loc->addChild("event");
$event->addAttribute("start", "2013-05-20 10:00:00");
$event->addAttribute("end", "2013-05-20 14:30:00");
$event->addChild("title", "some title");
$event->addChild("subtitle", "some subtitle");
$event->addChild("description", "some description");
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/12xtVD

Comment: thank you man you just made my day I've been struggling with my code since the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to create a child element. This is how I would go about doing this:

PHP:

```
$eleone=$_POST['elementone'];
           $eletwo=$_POST['elementtwo'];
           $file = "verbs.xml";
           $openf = fopen($file, "c+") or die ("Cannot open file");
           $str = fread ($openf, filesize($file));
           $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
           $xml->formatOutput=TRUE;
           $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
           $xml ->loadXML($openf) or die ("There has been an error with opening the XML file. Our team has been notified and will start working to fix this problem.");

           //this is the original document
           echo "<xmp>OLD:\n". $xml->saveXML(). "<xmp>";

           //this is how you get the document element
           $root= $xml ->documentElement;
           $firstnode= $root->firstChild;

           //good stuff right here; how to make a node
           $ori= $firstnode->childNodes->item(2);
           $eleadd= $xml->createElement($elementone);
           $eleaddt= $xml->createTextNode($//what gets shown in $eleadd );
           $eleadd->appendChild("$idt");
```

If you don't want all of this, you may be able to delete some non-crucial things like the parent elements. If you need more information, http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Adding-XML-Nodes-P414.html is the place to go, or where I found my information.

Comment: Max, I appreciate your code-example, and I think he should first try something himself...

Comment: How do you mean, he should try something himself first?

Comment: 1) You can directly open the content with just one line `DOMDocument::load($pathToFile);` 2) the last 3 lines are a little bit confusing, and finally you are not adding the new node to the xml tree. Try to give a complete working example in order to help...

Comment: @Max: his question doesn't show any effort to solve the problem, but is asking to get code. This is quite contrary to SO's purpose.

Comment: thanks max for you kind replay iv been trying to find a way to modify an exciting xml file in a 2nd node , @michi trust me iv been trying since the morning

Comment: @MatRt this the case am trying to solve i just to cehck if the event is already been created or not if its created post under that event

Comment: Guys, we don't need to get in an argument about this. What has been done has been done. It is outrageous how, in an atmosphere like this, people can be so inconsiderate with what they say. We are all programmers and we go through speed bumps at all times in our career, this may be one of those times.

Comment: @Max thank you for your help man , i just updated my question with the php code i hope you understand what am trying to do

Comment: Hey, I didn't mean to get into an argument, sorry bout that.